# How to return bool from MSFT-MVC action to jQuery $.ajax()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am calling a MSFT-MVC action using jQuery $.ajax()

```
public bool SetActivePatient(string patientID)
{
```

which returns a boolean.

The $.ajax() call is always firing the error option.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Services/SetActivePatient',
  data: { 'patientID': id },
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(returnVal) {
  if (returnVal == "True") {
     ...
    }
    else {
      alert('Error setting active patient return value, PatientID=' + id);
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Error in ajax call');
  }
});
```

The MVC action is called and works correctly, returning "True" as a .NET bool. Looking in FireBug the response is "True" from the MVC action. Do I have the wrong dataType?

Comment: So what was it? You can't specify `bool` as a return type for ajax requests? ONly JSON result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your error signature to:

```
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
{
//inspect xhr.responseText, thrownError variables to find out what is the exact error.
//Once we know the exact error, it could be debugged further. 
};
```

Comment: Here's the error information being return

    xhr
    {...}
    onreadystatechange: {???}
    readyState: 4
    responseBody: {...}
    responseStream: {...}
    responseText: "True"
    responseXML: {...}
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"

    ajaxOptions
    "parsererror"

    thrownError
    undefined