# What to return from ASP.NET MVC action to allow jQuery ajax success event to fire?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Right now my ajax posts all fire their Error events even if the action did not cause an error.  I have an ASP.NET MVC action that looks like:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public virtual ActionResult StuffToDo(int id)
{
     // do various things that work ...
     return new JsonResult(); // i have to return something, so this...
}
```

On the client side I have this jQuery:

```
$('#actionClick').click(function() {
     if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/Customer/StuffToDo/<%= Model.Customer.Id %>",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: "{}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function() {
                 ShowSuccessResult("Yay!");
             },
             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 ShowErrorResult("Boo! Message:" + xhr.responseText);
             }
         });
      }
      return false;
 });
```

If the action is successful (no exceptions thrown) then I would expect the success event handler to be triggered.  Instead the error event is firing.  Is there something I should pass back or change in the action so the success event fires?

I realize this question is basically the same as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080858/how-to-return-bool-from-msft-mvc-action-to-jquery-ajax), but my error handler already has the expanded signature which solved the other person's question.

I changed the return value to Null to see if that affected anything, but no behavior change.

Its starting to look like this is an issue with HTTPS.  I get multiple responses from the request.  The first 2 are 401 messages and then I get a 200.

Comment: can u post a screenshot of the firebug request response from console

Comment: And what's the xhr.responseText?

Comment: Firebug says I'm getting a 200.

Comment: @Drew - the responseText is an empty string.  The ajaxOptions shows as "parseerror" in the watch list.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're not returning anything in the JsonResult.  Try:

```
return this.Json(string.Empty);
```

and see if that works.  I think that the problem is that you're returning nothing to the jQuery call rather than an empty JSON set:

```
{}
```

Comment: JsonResult accepts no arguments.  I changed the return to a null but that did not affect the outcome.

Comment: @Sailing Judo - I boned that one and fixed the code example.  Controller exposes a Json() method that accepts an object and returns a JsonResult object.

Comment: this was the problem!  i would have never expected this in a million years.  nice solve.

Answer (score 17):

Returning an empty result may also be useful

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

Note: Your return type doesn't need to be ActionResult or event anything that inherits from it. In fact mvc will let you call any public method. However you should always use the most explicit return type you want just like any other method (like JsonResult).

Answer (score 10):

2 quick notes for anyone landing here struggling to trigger the ajax jQuery `success` callback from an MVC controller:

1. If you're using `type: "GET"` in your Ajax, you'll need to include `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to bypass the default anti [JSON Hijacking security measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed)

```
 return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

2. As per above, if you've indicated `dataType: 'json'` in the Ajax request, if you are making a one-way call (e.g. `Save`) where you don't need anything back, you can return just about anything serializable as `Json` from the controller. But with a 200, something must be returned. Use a 204 if no data is returned.

*Wrong - Triggers the Ajax `error` handler !*

```
 // Nope - Status 200 must have some content
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);

 // Also returns a 200 with no data - not allowed
 return new EmptyResult();
```

*Works - triggers the Ajax success handler:*

```
 // Return a 204 if there's no data
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

 // Return something with a 200 return
 return Json(new {Success = true});
```

Comment: This was my issue.  I was doing a GET and forgot about AllowGet, so the return was actually throwing an exception and so my javascript was handling that as a failure.

Answer (score -3):

The return type on your method should be JsonResult instead of ActionResult.

Comment: A JsonResult is an ActionResult.